# GPS - Reduce the Time To First Fix (TTFF) in C# On Toughbook MK5 CF19

Tags: c#, gps

i'm developping a software in C# with the Panasonic SDK that will be installed on different panasonics CF-19 laptop.

I am facing a problem about the Time To First Fix (TTFF) that take more than 40min.

Someone knows if it's possible to reduce this time with Almanac, or connecting on specific serveur, injecting files thanks to the SDK or something else ?

Big Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you receive a strong enough signal (antenna?) I think with a bad receiver (single channel) the TTFF is about 15 Minutes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix

Comment: Hello and thanks.  Yes i'm sure because after TTFF, each time i switch ON GPS and try to get Data ( after reboot laptop or software), the fix GPS is about 5 seconds.